# Solve SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent. What permission do I need?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open the play store from app. It's fine in Samsung, but it failed in OnePlus mobile. 
I don't know where does the ***alibaba*** come from. It's strange.

*Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://play.google.com/... cmp=com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon/com.alibaba.android.intl.weex.activity.WeexPageActivity } from ProcessRecord{a1dd30c 15827:a2bliving.ie.a2b/u0a151} (pid=15827, uid=10151) not exported from uid 10156*

Code:

```
private static final String PLAY_STORE_LINK = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s&hl=en";

public void openUpdateLink() {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getExternalAppLink())));
    }

 public String getExternalAppLink() {
        return String.format(PLAY_STORE_LINK, context.getPackageName());
    }
```

Comment: Asked already use search

Comment: Same problem is occurred in my app. I don't figure out this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `android:exported="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.anurag.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="Demo" 
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Do you mean I should set my activity as android:exported="true"?

Comment: @AnuragAggarwal: Miao Yichong is not the developer of `com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon/com.alibaba.android.i‌ntl.weex.activity.We‌​exPageActivity`. That is the activity that is not exported and triggering this exception.

Answer (score 6):

On that device, that `Intent` is getting modified to add a specific component (`com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon/com.alibaba.android.intl.weex.activity.WeexPageActivity`). I do not know if that is from the system chooser or something else. And, the activity that it resolves to is not exported.

So, mostly, this is a bug in that device.

However, since the activity is not exported, there is nothing you can do to start that specific activity.

Comment: Do I need set my activity as exported?

Comment: I also believe it's the problem of that device ROM.

Comment: @MiaoYichong: "Do I need set my activity as exported?" -- your activity is not the problem. It is the exported state of `com.alibaba.intl.android.apps.poseidon/com.alibaba.android.intl.weex.activity.WeexPageActivity`. My guess is that you do not control that activity.

Comment: Yes. "com.alibaba.android" is not under my control. So  Aggarwal's answer will not solve my problem, isn't it ?

Comment: @MiaoYichong: Correct.

Comment: @CommonsWare I faced the same issue with Viber: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 cmp=com.viber.voip/.messages.ui.forward.ForwardActivity (has clip) (has extras) }`

Comment: @CommonsWare I have fixed the issue by setting more specific Intent type

Comment: Just wanted to second the answer by reporting another culprit: cmp=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ActivityWebBrowser

Comment: @AndriiAbramov could you share your solution with the more specific intent type here? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Terry that happened years ago... Unfortunately, I haven't dealt with Android for 3 years (

Answer (score 4):

**This is not a bug in your app**, but a bug in the Alibaba app. What happened was that they declared their activity WeexPageActivity to handle http/https/file schemes, but also made it not exported. So, every time your app tries to start an intent with one of these schemes and the Alibaba app is chosen or worse it's set as default YOUR app will crash.

For instance, if you use AdMob this will happen every time a user clicks on an ad (for me the latest culprit app is mxtech.videoplayer.ActivityWebBrowser).

Honestly, I don't know why Android doesn't ignore said activities instead of crashing or why the other developers would make said mistake, but it is not your fault.

Comment: I am also facing this crash due to mxtech.videoplayer.ActivityWebBrowser

Answer (score 2):

This is a good one. Some other app is trying to handle my Intent(which they can't handle) and my poor app is getting crashed. Thanks, Android.

Anyway, to fix it you need to add

```
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
```

to your intent, if it's a URL you are trying to open. Otherwise, you need to specify the app that you want to handle your intent.