# Java Appium error 500 while doing automation on PNB mobile android app

Tags: java, android, automation, adb, appium-android

Here is [my script](https://ideone.com/cC16q8) for doing automation in Java using Appium.

There is an error that I’m getting after running this script is,

```
debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1535090782935 (11:36:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.infosys.android.ui' application. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/shubhambansal/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 42007dee9bec64d3 shell am start -W -n com.infosys.android.ui/com.infosys.android.ui.controller.GroupMainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.infosys.android.ui/.controller.GroupMainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } } from null (pid=5830, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10136
[W3C]   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1704)
[W3C]   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1654)
[W3C]   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3716)
[W3C]   at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:658)
[W3C]   at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:392)
[W3C]   at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
[W3C]   at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:125)
[W3C]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[W3C]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:315)'; Code: '1'
[W3C]     at ADB.callee$0$0$ (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-utils.js:125:11)
[W3C]     at tryCatch (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
[W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 31877 ms - 3846
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360074/appium-activity-used-to-start-app-doesnt-exist-or-cannot-be-launched-make-sure/50366915#50366915

Comment: make sure your appPackage and appActivity names are correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent. What permission do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963980/solve-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent-what-permission-do)